# Javascript access element from return value of ajax call in JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, ajax

So I make an ajax call that does return successfully but the problem is that I cannot access individual elements of the array it returns, meaning I can't console log it. It returns either error or undefined. Error would be like track is not defined but when you look at the example ajax return, track is there. Here is the code

```
$.ajax({
            url: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/playlists/'+playlist+'/tracks?fields=items(track.id)',
            headers: {
              'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token
            },
            success: function(response,access_token) {
              Result(response,access_token);
            },
            dataType:"json"
        });

function Result(response,access_token){
      console.log(response[0].track.id);
      console.log(response[0]);
      console.log(response.track);
    }
```

The ajax call returns an array that looks like this for example. Inspecting an individual element.

```
items: Array(80)
 -0:
  -track:
   -id: "Random String"
```

I read up on JSON methods and how it handles arrays and when I console logged response[0].track.id I believe I should see the id string. I also tried different console logs as well but have omitted because they all have the same kind of errors. I am trying to do this cause at one point I might put these ids in their own array and will need to add each individual element one at a time for further use. Thank you for any assistance and let me know if you need more details.

Comment: Show us the actual error message, along with a full request/response.

Comment: From the inspected value... it looks like you should check `response.items[0].track.id` instead...

Comment: Are you sure it isn't `response.items[0].track.id`?

Comment: So I would like to apologize, I had created a variable at one point called items and was using that so instead of response.items I was doing items.track. Thank you for your time though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the inspected value... it looks like you should check `response.items[0].track.id` instead...

Comment: Yeah my B. I had a variable called items at one point and was doing items.track. Thank you.

Comment: Glad I could help... :)